# Скролл по горизонтали с двумя рядами внутри

Tags: html, css

У меня есть контейнер, внутри которого должны быть два ряда блоков, расположенных горизонтально, а не вертикально. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эти два ряда остались горизонтальными, и я мог прокручивать их по горизонтали. Я добавил скролл по горизонтали, но блоки все равно уходят друг под друга(в плане не идут дальше в ряд а уходят в колонку). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы контейнер list__block не выходил за рамки контейнера wrapper, и мог прокручиваться по горизонтали.

```css
.wrapper {
   width: 1200px;
   height: 608px;
   background-color: blue;
   margin: auto;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
.list__block {
   margin-left: auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 580px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   gap: 20px;
}
.item__block {
   width: 450px;
   height: 247px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="list__block">
         <li class="item__block"></li>
         <li class="item__block"></li>
         <li class="item__block"></li>
         <li class="item__block"></li>
         <li class="item__block"></li>
         <li class="item__block"></li>
         <li class="item__block"></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```